# dynamic vertical align with css

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV with an icon on left side, and text on right side.
The text is dynamic and can be short or long.
If the text is short (A row or two) I want it to be centered to the icon.
If it's long, I want them to be vertically top-aligned.
Is there a way to do it with CSS only (no line counting)?

[image]

```
 <div class="container" >
          <div class="container__left">
            <div class="container__left__icon" />
          </div>
          <div class="container__right">
            // some react code with dynamic text in <div>s and <span>s
          </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: display:flex on the container and margin:auto 0 to the right container (I am seaching for the duplicate ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: table-cell` and different vertical aligns - top for the first cell and middle for the second.

```css
.inner1{
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:top;
}
.inner2{
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div class="inner1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100"></div>
 <div class="inner2">some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some  </div>
</div>

<div>
 <div class="inner1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100"></div>
 <div class="inner2">some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some  some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some  some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some  some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some  some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some  some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
}
```

You can use Flex Box CSS to do this very easily. You apply the flex to the parent div, establish the direction you want the boxes to fill the space (vertical or horizontal - in this case horizontally so we want to add a "row" direction"), and finally center those elements vertically using align-items set to center. This will account for any changes in the content in your right hand box. It also later makes making it responsive very easy.